Is a docker image pulled and commands executed locally when an external github action is called?
I am curious how an external github action acts on my repo when it is called in a github actions workflow. Suppose I call an external action, let's call it thirdparty/thirdpartyaction@v1, how does it actually act on my local repository? Is a docker image from thirdparty pulled to my actions runner and then the commands relevant to thirdpartyaction run locally against the code in my repo? Could someone please tell me how it works under the hood? Your insights would be greatly appreciated.

Yes, the docker image is pulled if needed (some or all layers may already be cached). You can simply run a sample workflow and observe all the logs. You might want to go through the workflow syntax for multiple use cases of containers.

So what happens under the hood is a docker run thirdpartyimage thirdpartycommand?

The repo thirdparty/thirdpartyaction is downloaded by your workflow runner and then action.yaml file is interpreted. If it says  using: 'docker', then docker run is executed on your runner in the context of your repo. You should see docker run command in the logs.
